# Area above a surface

Tags: integration, area, surfaces

I have to find the area of the surface
$$x+y+z=5$$
localizated above the region $x^{2}+y^{2}\leq9$$.

I did:
$$z=5-x-y\Rightarrow z_{x}=z_{y}=-1$$
So the area is
$$\int\int_{R}\sqrt{1+z_{x}^{2}+z_{y}^{2}}dxdy$$
where $R$ is the region $x^{2}+y^{2}\leq9$$

Using polar coordinates, I got:
$$x=r\sin\theta, y=r\cos\theta$$
where $$r\in[0,3]$$ and $$\theta\in[0,2\pi]$$

So the area is
$$A=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{3}\sqrt{3}rdrd\theta$$
And when I evaluate it, I get $9\sqrt{3}\pi$, but the answer in the book is $6\pi$. Where is my mistake?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the plane lies completely above the circle. The area of the circle is $9\pi$. The area of the ellipse on the plane above it has to be bigger than that, so $6\pi$ looks wrong to me. That does not mean that your answer is correct, but it does mean that the answer in the book is wrong (modulo mistakes on my part of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer squares with the one I got using plain analytic geometry.  The area of an ellipse is $\pi ab$, where $a$ and $b$ are the semimajor and semiminor axes, that is, the greatest and least distance from the center of the ellipse.

The center of the ellipse is at $(0,0,5)$.  Since $z=5-x-y$, the greatest $z$-value occurs when $x+y$ is least, at $x = y = -\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}$.  So the semimajor axis is the distance from $(0,0,5)$ to $\left(-\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}},5+2\sqrt{3}\right)$, and this is $3\sqrt{3}$.

In the perpendicular direction, the semiminor axis is the distance from $(0,0,5)$ to $\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt2},-\frac{3}{\sqrt2},5\right)$, which is $3$.  So the area is
$$
    \pi(3)(3\sqrt{3}) = 9\pi\sqrt{3}
$$